# Inno Setup: Compare the content of two files

Tags: inno-setup

I have a little code that merge two text files (the first at the and of the second). How can I check if the contents of the first file is just inside the second and skip the merge?

---

```pascal
[Code]
procedure AppendFile(const SrcFile, DestFile: string);
var
  SrcStream: TFileStream;
  DestStream: TFileStream;
begin
  SrcStream := TFileStream.Create(SrcFile, fmOpenRead);
  try
    DestStream := TFileStream.Create(DestFile, fmOpenWrite);
    try
      DestStream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
      DestStream.CopyFrom(SrcStream, SrcStream.Size);
    finally
      DestStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SrcStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: where can i find an exemple?

Comment: What code for merging do you use? Is it Inno Setup Pascal Scripting code? Can you show it to us? Or do you use an external tool?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qg77yC3T this is the code i'm using :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest Unicode-safe implementation is using [`TStringList` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TStringList):

```pascal
function NeedAppend(const SrcFile, DestFile: string): Boolean;
var
  SrcContents: TStringList;
  DestContents: TStringList;
begin
  SrcContents := TStringList.Create();
  DestContents := TStringList.Create();
  try
    SrcContents.LoadFromFile(SrcFile);
    DestContents.LoadFromFile(DestFile);

    Result := (Pos(SrcContents.Text, DestContents.Text) = 0);
  finally
    SrcContents.Free;
    DestContents.Free;
  end;

  if not Result then
  begin
    Log('Contents present already, will not append');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Contents not present, will append');
  end;
end;
```

Though it is not very efficient, if the files are large.

---

Once you have the diffing implemented this way, you can combine that with merging to this simple code:

```pascal
procedure AppendFileIfNeeded(const SrcFile, DestFile: string);
var
  SrcContents: TStringList;
  DestContents: TStringList;
begin
  SrcContents := TStringList.Create();
  DestContents := TStringList.Create();
  try
    SrcContents.LoadFromFile(SrcFile);
    DestContents.LoadFromFile(DestFile);

    if Pos(SrcContents.Text, DestContents.Text) > 0 then
    begin
      Log('Contents present already, will not append');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Contents not present, will append');

      DestContents.AddStrings(SrcContents);
      DestContents.SaveToFile(DestFile);
    end;
  finally
    SrcContents.Free;
    DestContents.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Simplest, ehm, if this is about ANSI only files, then I would call simplest (less code lines, efficiency similar, maybe a bit better) using `LoadStringFromFile` and `SaveStringToFile` with `Append` parameter set to True.

Comment: True. I actually avoided the `LoadStringFromFile` because of its problems with ANSI files.